# Search for a value in a sheet using loop in Google Apps Script

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below code searches for a value found in SheetOne, Cell B60, in SheetTwo, Column A.

If the value is found in column A of SheetTwo, a message box will display the value of the cell adjacent to where the cell was found. My problem is though the code works, I would also like a message box to appear if no match is found. Everything I have tried either traps me in the loop, or yields no result.

```
 {
 var MyWB = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var ValueSheet =  MyWB.getSheetByName("SheetOne");
 var SearchValue = ValueSheet.getRange("B60").getValue()

 var SearchSheet = MyWB.getSheetByName("SheetTwo");   
 var SearchRange = SearchSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();


  for (var i = 0, len = SearchRange.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (SearchRange[i][0] == SearchValue) {

      var MyFound = SearchSheet.getRange(i+1,2).getValue()
      Browser.msgBox(MyFound)
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To show a message no matter what, you'll want to update an existing variable if you find a match, and otherwise print a default message:

```
var message = "";
for(i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if(array[i] == myValue) {
        message += sheet.getRange(i, column).getValue();
        break;
    }
}
Browser.msgBox(message.length ? message : "Did not find the desired value");
```

Comment: Thank You, tehhowch! Your solution worked perfectly  - I am in your debt. Forgive my ignorance, but what is the purpose of the "?", please?

Comment: @Tacitus the `?` is a ternary operator (also called a conditional operator). It's essentially an "inline" `if`.
In my example I've made sure message is a string, so to see if it has been given a value (without setting an additional boolean value when finding the match), we test the length to see if it is a non-zero-length string. If it is, we know a value was found and stored.

Comment: Ahhhh - - brilliant in its simplicity. Thank You for what I have learned form you today! I am grateful.